# Oracle, how to remove almost same rows from the table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11gr2

Over the years a few duplicates were added to our data tables as a result of spelling mistakes. So for example someone misspelled the name and instead of O'leary wrote Oleary. Our system thinks its a totally different name and does not complain about it, however in most cases its the same contact entered twice(I didn't build this system).

Now what I want to do is remove all of these duplicates, but I am having hard time building a query to display them all. I did experiment with UTL_MATCH and wrote a query that would return all similar names if I supply the name.

```
select first_name from customers 
where UTL_MATCH.edit_distance_similarity(first_name,'Oleary') > 60
order by first_name;
```

However I would like to build a query that would automatically return all possible duplicates without having to supply the name. Could anyone point me in the correct direction please?

Comment: There is a logical inconsistency in the problem statement. It is possible to have three first_names, call them fn1, fn2, fn3 with fn1 and fn3 both "sufficiently similar" to fn2, but not "sufficiently similar" to each other. In this case you could either keep fn2 and remove the other two, OR you could keep both fn1 and fn3 but remove the middle one. And then fn3 could be similar to fn4 but fn4 is not "sufficiently" similar to fn1, etc. You need a more clearly specified problem statement before you can think about ANY solution.

Comment: I'm sorry mathguy maybe the difference between our IQ levels got in the way(I didn't understand what you just said), however I did my best to explain my problem as simple as possible, I see some answers below that almost answer my query, so it seems I didn't fail completely. But thank you for your input.

Comment: Explaining by way of example: Three different versions of the same name, spelled differently (for whatever reason), but same person. First name is JADA, JEDA or GEDA. "Similarly" is how many letters in common. JADA to JEDA is 75% (they are over 60% similar), JEDA and GEDA also 75%, but JADA and GEDA only 50% similar. If you use your query and in the distance_similarity you use 'JEDA', both other names will be selected. But if you use 'JADA' for comparison, 'GEDA' will not be selected. So the concept of "all duplicates" is not well defined.

Comment: By the same logic, if "the friend of my friend is my friend" should be applied, you may have a situation like this: ABC is similar to DBC, which is similar to DEC, which is similar to DEF. Does this mean ABC is similar to DEF?

Comment: Ha! Now I understand :) Thank you! I think if one was to implement your idea the query stated below would become much more efficient, but perhaps there is no need this time as I can get the job done and I will only have to do it once, so speed is not that important.

Comment: I subdivided my query by locations, its all good I will have to run it multiple times, but as I said - only once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would technically work.

```
select c1.first_name, c2.first_name
  from customers c1
       cross join customers c2
 where utl_match.edit_distance_similarity( c1.first_name, c2.first_name ) > 60
 order by c1.first_name
```

However, it would be extremely slow unless your `customers` table happens to be very (very) small since you're comparing every row in the `customers` table against every other row in the table (and your edit distance similarity cut-off is pretty low).  In order to make that faster, you're probably going to have to make assumptions about your data or do something else that can be a preliminary filter.  For example, if you assume that any duplicates start with the same first character or the same first few characters ignoring punctuation, then you can dramatically decrease the number of pairs that need to be matched at the risk of missing the fact that "Kustin" may be a typo duplicate of "Justin" where the first character is different.  Requiring that `c2.customer_id > c1.customer_id` would be another reasonable filter to consider assuming that you don't need every pair duplicated (i.e. a "Kustin/ Justin" row can exist without the equivalent "Justin/ Kustin" row).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have tried a very similar approach and had to cancel my query after 5 minutes, it was still running, I thought there was something wrong with my code. Any way to increase its speed?

Comment: @K.I - Like I said, it would very slow to compare every row in the table against every row in the table.  You'd need to come up with some reasonable way to limit the combinations you need to consider based on some knowledge of your data.  I mentioned a few possibilities that may or may not be reasonable for you.  Unfortunately, it's hard to guess at what might be reasonable heuristics for your data.  Maybe your customers have address information and you can only compare customers in the same ZIP code, for example.  Or maybe you can let it run for hours overnight.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this for a `join`:

```
select c1.first_name, c2.first_name
from customers c1 join
     customers c2
     on UTL_MATCH.edit_distance(c1.first_name, c2.first_name) <= 3
order by c1.first_name;
```

Notes:

- I prefer `edit_distance()` to `edit_distance_similarity()`, because I understand the units.
- The join will be slow, slow, slow, so hopefully you don't have *too* many rows.
- There are likely to be a lot of false matches, so be careful.

Comment: I would just add a `and c1.first_name < c2.first_name`  in the join clause to avoid useless duplicates (and exact matches)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have tried a very similar approach and had to cancel my query after 5 minutes, it was still running, I thought there was something wrong with my code. Any way to increase its speed?

Comment: @K.I . . . Start with a small chunk of the table, such as names that start with "A" and see how that goes.